# Amplifying the correctness of $\mathsf{RP}$ algorithms using expander graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, randomized-algorithms, expanders

A graph $G = (V, E)$ is called an $(n, d, \varepsilon)$-*expander* if the graph has $n$ vertices, maximum degree $d$, and satisfies the following *expansion property*:

- for every subset $W\subset V$ such that $|W|\leq n/2$, $|W\cup N(W)|\ge (1+\varepsilon)|W|$

where $N(W)$ is the neighborhood of $W$ in $G$.  The expansion property means, informally, that the neighborhood of $W$ is "large" when $W$ is "small".  That expanders exist can be shown with the probabilistic method (see, e.g., this [writeup from Ellis](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~dce27/randomreggraphs3.pdf)).

I'm trying to show that expanders can be used to amplify the success probability of one-sided Monte Carlo algorithms.  In particular, given a polynomial time algorithm $A$ for a problem in [RP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:R#rp) that uses $n$ random bits and gives false negatives with probability at most $1/2$ we want to show there is a polynomial time algorithm that uses $n$ random bits and gives false negatives with probability at most $n^{-c}$ for a fixed constant $c$.

Here is the method I've been asked to analyze.  We regard $A$ as a function $A(x,r)$ where $x$ is the input and $r$ is a string representing the random bits.  On the input $x$ we then:

- Fix a $(2^n,d,\varepsilon)$-expander $G$ and identify its vertices with $\{0,1\}^n$
- Select a vertex $r$ of $G$ uniformly at random
- Compute the set $y_1,y_2,\ldots, y_t$ of vertices at distance at most $\delta$ from $r$ in $G$
- Say "no" if and only if $A(x,r),A(x,y_1), \ldots, A(x,y_t)$ are all "no"

What I need to show is that for $\delta = O(\log n)$ the probability of a false negative is at most $n^{-c}$.

As a side note, this is actually enough to accomplish the original goal.  A result of [Gabber and Galil](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000081900404) is that there is a family of $(2^n, 5,(2 - \sqrt{3})/4)$-expanders with the additional property that the neighbors of any vertex can be enumerated in polynomial time.  This means that $d$ and $\varepsilon$ can be taken uniformly in $n$, and that we can implement BFS from $r$ in polynomial time per vertex considered. Since $t\le d^{\delta + 1}$, the new algorithm runs $A$ a number of times polynomial in $n$ for $\delta = O(\log n)$ and $n$ is polynomial in the input size.  Since $G$ is deterministic and does not depend on $A$, there is also clearly no new randomness.

---

Here is how I approached the problem thus far.

Let $G$ be given. Since $|V| = 2^n$, we have an identification $V \cong \{0,1\}^n$. Let $r \in \{0,1\}^n$ be chosen at random so that $r$ corresponds to a random starting point in $G$. Define a ball $B(v,\delta) = \{u \in V: d(u,v) \leq \delta\}$ where $d(u,v)$ is the length of the shortest $uv$-path. We are only interested in the number of *bad balls*, namely balls such that all $u\in B(v,\delta)$ result in false negatives, that is, our $\mathsf{RP}$ algorithm should accept but reject nonetheless. If we can bound above the number of bad balls by $2^n/n^c$ for some constant $c$, then we are done since an error occur if and only if the chosen vertex $y_i$ is such that $B(y_i,\delta)$ is bad.

I tried bounding the number of vertices in a bad ball using the expansion property of $G$, but I am not sure how this could help considering balls are certainly not disjoint. We also know that at most $1/2$ of the vertices will result in a false negative.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a hint: The expansion property will let you work out the size of the ball $B$.  Now try to get a bound on the probability that all the vertices in a particular ball give you a false negative.

Comment: @Louis, are you saying the probability of having a bad ball at $v$ is at most $(1/2)^s$ where $s$ is the size of the ball?

Comment: It's not a uniform set, but you are trying to show you get something close enough.  Notice that we have a partition of $[2^n]$ into $X$ and $Y$ so that $Y$ never gives false negatives.  What you need to figure out is the probability that $B(v,\delta)$ stays entirely within $X$. (Intuitively, it will be hard for the graph to expand if a lot of vertices have all their neighbors within $X$.  Try to use this.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since nobody else answered, here is what I had in mind when I made my comment.  The basic idea behind the proposed amplification algorithm is that expanders are "negatively curved" in the sense that small sets in degree-bounded expanders should have a lot of their volume near the boundary. This then suggests that a ball centered in a small set should quickly "escape" with reasonable probability.

To answer a question from your comment, since the ball around a random vertex isn't a uniformly random set, we wouldn't expect a bound like $2^{-s}$ for the probability of being bad. Instead we get something that depends on $\epsilon$ and $d$ (with bigger $\epsilon$ and smaller $d$ being better if the other parameter is held fixed).

As in my comment, set $X\subset \{0,1\}^n$ to be the random strings where our RP algorithm $A(x,r)$ gives false negatives and $Y$ be the complement.  Since $G$ is a $(N,d,\epsilon)$-expander with $N = 2^n$, and $|X|\le N/2$ by hypothesis, we know that:

- at least $\epsilon |X| / d$ different vertices in $X$ have a neighbor in $Y$

Notice that this already gives us something, since if we took $\delta = 1$, the improved algorithm now gives a false negative with probability only $1/2 - \epsilon/d$. The question just asks us to be a bit more ambitious.

To this end, define
$$
X_i := \{r : d(r,Y) \ge i\}
$$
What we just argued was that $|X_2| \le (1-\epsilon/d)|X|\le (1-\epsilon/d)N/2$.  From the way we've defined $X_i$, we the neighborhood of $X_i$ is contained in $X_{i-1}$ for $i\ge 3$.  This lets us replay the same argument to show that, for $i\ge 3$ we get $|X_i|\le (1-\epsilon/d)|X_{i-1}|$.  By induction we then get that  $|X_s|\le (1-\epsilon/d)^{s-1}N/2$.

Finally, observe that the improved algorithm fails when the chosen $r$ is in $X_{s+1}$. For $s=\Theta_{\epsilon,d}(\log n)$ this probability is $n^{-c}$.